# Why does Groovy's Map.get set a value?

Tags: groovy

Is it just me, or is this completely not intuitive and dangerous?

[Map.get](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object))

Shouldn't they have called it something like `getOrSet[Default]`?

Comment: You are referring to the `get(key,defaultValue)` variant. You can always use `get(key)` method if needed. This variant has no side effects. Keep in mind that `get(key, defaultValue)` method was implemented before Groovy 1.0 was released (January 2nd, 2007). The context matters, and we cannot judge if the decision was right or not without knowing what developers knew back in 2007.

Comment: Yes, but that method is not confusing and has no side-effects - it has no problems and therefor was not relevant to my questions.

Comment: Then, maybe the real question is, why hasn't it been deprecated ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's perfectly fine naming. You could name it like `getOrSetForTheFirstTime()` which would not make much sense.

If you need default value in the "safe way" i.e. w/o setting it back to the map instance, you could use the elvis operator:

```
def val = map[ '42' ] ?: '21'
```

Close analogue to `get()` is [withDefault{}](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#withDefault(groovy.lang.Closure)) which is used more often.

Comment: Yeah, I was using `Objects.toString(value, '')` later on, so I reworked it to use the normal get and `Objects.toString(value, defaultValue)`. Dozens of ways to fix it. My concern was about the naming. No one expects a getter to modify the underlying object.

Comment: well that was obviously not a getter